# OLEDB JET and NULL value for Boolean Type

Tags: sql, null, boolean, oledb, dbase

I have to move data from an old application written in Delphi/BDE (DBase IV) to a new one using VisualStudio 2008/SQLServer. I'm fairly new to VS. To connect to the dbase tables from visual Studio, i use OLEDB JET 4.0 and I'm having troubles querying my table against boolean values.

Let's say my table contains an integer and a boolean field (or Logical field ?)

```
1 true
2 NULL
3 false
```

`SELECT * from mytable` will display in the bottom grid of visual studio

```
1 true
2 false
3 false
```

NULL seems to default to false (BDE used to do the same), which is fine by me. I think NULL values for a boolean field don't make sens anyway. 
But then

`SELECT * from mytable where field2 IS NOT NULL` displays the same result

`SELECT * from mytable where field2 IS NULL` displays an empty resultset

and the best :

`SELECT * from mytable where field2 = true` will display in the bottom grid

```
1 true
2 false
```

so the question is : do NULL values for boolean type default to true ? (and the grid is just misbehaving by displaying them as "false"?) or does is default to false ? in which case my oledb dll might be outdated or buggy (why not) ?

Comment: What if you try `SELECT * from mytable where field2 <> NULL` ?

Comment: didn't think of it but... unfortunately, Same result as SELECT * from mytable where field2 IS NOT NULL

Comment: Weird. What about something like `SELECT * from mytable where field2 IN (0,1)` ?

Comment: It's getting weirder : the result is 3 false (i'm a bit lost now....)

Comment: How many records are total in `mytable`? Only 3 - true, NULL, false?

Comment: Yep ! I've also tried `SELECT * from mytable where fields2 in (0)` -> 3-false, and then `SELECT * from mytable where fields2 in (-1)` -> 1-true and 2-NULL (displayed as "false"), and then SELECT * from mytable where fields2 in (1) -> empty resultset

Comment: Sorry. My answer to the question `SELECT * from mytable where field2 IN (0,1)` should have been : one record in the result : 3-false.  but I've just realised that what you where trying to suggest me was probably `SELECT * from Mytable where fields2 in (-1,0)`, is that right ? If that's the case, when executing this query, all 3 records are in the result

Comment: Are you sure the data is not being changed? I can see number of rows retrieved being different, but not the value of the fields.

Comment: The table is located on my computer only, has been crafted just for the example and is not used by any other app other than visual studio (through the OLEDB Jet). I'll have to dig dipper as for why NULL and True default to -1(=true) and false to 0 (=false). Seems unusual for me but I haven't worked with many DBMS to know for sure. I've tried to cast the field with CBOOL with no more success. I wonder if there's no option somewhere in the connectionstring Extended Properties that could modify this behaviour. Just an idea... thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Just checked - all works fine. Please provide your connection string.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not excatly answering my own question but some progress has been made since i asked it.
I've been trying different versions of msjet40.dll and MSJETOLEDB40.dll.
In the original post, I used :

***Windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2008 SP1,***
*MSJETOLEDB40.dll 4.0.9756.0*
*MSJET40.dll 4.0.9765.0*

(and before you ask, there is no typing mistake : it is 9765, not 9756 for MSJET40, I've checked twice).
The results were the one's described in the first post, that is  : NULL boolean values seems to default to True but grid displays false and IS NULL doesn't see the NULL values. I then tried :

***Windows XP SP3 + visual Studio 2008 (with and without SP1).***
*MSJETOLEDB40.dll 4.0.9502.0*
*MSJET40.dll 4.0.9511.0*

The results are slightly better (more consistent anyway): boolean NULL defaults to true and the Grid does indeed display "true" (instead of false in the windows 8.1 setup). But IS NULL still doesn't see the NULL values. Eventually I tried :

***Windows 7 SP1 + Visual Studio 2008 (with and without SP1),***
*MSJETOLEDB40.dll 4.0.9756.0*
*MSJET40.dll 4.0.9756.0*

Ah... Nice (at last !) : boolean NULL defaults to false and the Grid does indeed display "false". As for IS NULL, still doesn't see the NULL values but considering it defaults to false, I don't mind that anymore.

To answer Oleg question, Connection strings were the same in the 5 tests I've made :

*Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Cartociel\Descamps;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="dBase IV"*
For now, unless someone has a better idea, I suspect MSJET40 4.0.9765 is the culprit and I'll see if an older version of that dll could work on my windows 8.1 setup.

sorry for that long Post (and still working on it)...

Comment: Just for the info, I might give up on MsJet and go for that : http://fastdbf.codeplex.com/. Simple and fast enough for what I need